# How to replace existing value of ArrayList element in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to update an existing value of an `ArrayList` by using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    list.add( "Zero" );
    list.add( "One" );
    list.add( "Two" );
    list.add( "Three" );
    
    list.add( 2, "New" ); // add at 2nd index
    
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

I want to print `New` instead of `Two` but I got `[Zero, One, New, Two, Three]` as the result, and I still have `Two`. I want to print `[Zero, One, New, Three]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Use the [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method to replace the old value with a new one.

```
list.set( 2, "New" );
```

Answer (score 35):

If you are unaware of the position to replace, use list iterator to find and replace element
[ListIterator.set(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-)

```
ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     String next = iterator.next();
     if (next.equals("Two")) {
         //Replace element
         iterator.set("New");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 26):

Use [`ArrayList.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

```
list.set(2, "New");
```

Comment: What if I don't know the Index of Object, Still I want to replace the object with new in specific place. Is it possible?

Comment: @santhanam You can use list.set(list.indexOf(oldObject), newObject);

Comment: @Alberto what if it was the same element but updated ?

Comment: @MohammadAli override `equals` method of your object class and implement your own rules to check if objects are the same (equal), after that `List.contains(object)`, `List.indexOf(object)`, `object1.equals(object2)` will work ok

Comment: @santhanam Beware that indexOf will return the index of the first occurance of the element

Answer (score 4):

You must use

```
list.remove(indexYouWantToReplace);
```

first.

Your elements will become like this. `[zero, one, three]`

then add this

```
list.add(indexYouWantedToReplace, newElement)
```

Your elements will become like this. `[zero, one, new, three]`

Comment: this approach only works if you are not iterating through the list at the time of the _remove_ method call. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re) for more information