# Foreach can not manipulate a String list?

Tags: java, list, immutability, pass-by-value

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981008/how-to-replace-existing-value-of-arraylist-element-in-java) thread on the topic and I wondered why it's so hard in Java to replace a value in a List.

My code looks ugly like this:

```
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... add some elements
    for (int i = 0; i< stringList.size(); ++i) {
        if (stringList.get(i).contains("%")) {
            stringList.set(i, stringList.get(i).replace("%", backupStorePath));
        }
    }
```

Is this really the only way to do this? Why can't I use a foreach loop?

```
for (String command : stringList) {
    command = command.replace("%", backupStorePath);
}
```

This must be a java's "Copy by value" problem and String being immutable, but why was it implemented like that? Why is `command` a copy of the original reference and not the original itself?

Comment: Immutability is not the issue here. `command` is a variable that references to the n-th element of the list, but assigning a different value to this variable just causes it to reference something else, without any effect on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Java Programming Language: The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (***emphasis*** added)

> The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call `remove`. Therefore, the for-each loop is not usable for filtering. ***Similarly it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.*** Finally, it is not usable for loops that must iterate over multiple collections in parallel. These shortcomings were known by the designers, who made a conscious decision to go with a clean, simple construct that would cover the great majority of cases.

You could use an `Iterator` and an `index`. Something like

```
// ... add some elements
Iterator<String> stringIter = stringList.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (stringIter.hasNext()) {
    String command = stringIter.next();
    if (command.contains("%")) {
        command = command.replace("%", backupStorePath);
        stringList.set(i, command);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What would be the problem if you'd call "remove"?

Comment: @TrudleR There isn't a *visible* `iterator` to call `remove` on (with a `for-each` loop).

Answer (score 5):

Since Java-8 you have a new option to use [`List.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-):

```
stringList.replaceAll(command -> command.replace("%", backupStorePath));
```

Note that `for` loop works for any `Iterable`, not only `List`. And most of other iterables do not support the element replacement. So even if Java designers had decided to support modifications, it would be necessary to separate List and non-List cases which would certainly add some complexity.

Comment: This was the solution for my problem, thank you. But Eliotts answer fits better to the question. Thank you very much for this input! :)

Answer (score 0):

it will like be this:

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
List list 2 = list1;
list2 = new LinkedList();  //this just make list2 to point to an new Object no reference about list1.
```

so your code :

```
command = command.replace("%", backupStorePath);  //this just make command to a new point of memory not have any chang about your list
```